# Trying to use panda uploader with ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I'm trying to use the panda uploader in a rails app with ember.js.

The panda uploader is here:

http://www.pandastream.com/docs/uploader

Something in ember is interfering with the functionality.  Whenever you try to execute the following javascript code to initialize the panda uploader, an error occurs.

```
<script src="//cdn.pandastream.com/u/2.0/panda-uploader.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="panda_video_id"/>

<!-- upload progress bar (optional) -->
<div class='progress'><span id="progress-bar" class='bar'></span></div>

<!-- file selector -->
<div id="browse">Choose file</div>

<script>

  panda.uploader.init({
    'buttonId': 'browse',
    'progressBarId': 'progress-bar',
    'onSuccess': function(file, data) {
      alert('success');
      $("#panda_video_id").val(data.id)
    }
  });

</script>
```

The error I'm receiving is:

TypeError: a.attachEvent is not a function within anda-uploader.min.js.  Ember is definitely interfering with the functionality even if this code exists outside of an ember template.  Perhaps I"m doing something wrong because I'm relatively new to Ember.

Comment: I have.  It is not getting to the point where it does a post to "/panda/authorize_upload" on the local machine (which I have properly set up).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {   
         var upl = panda.uploader.init({
                'buttonId': "browse-files",
                'maxFileSize': '10MB',
                'confirmBeforeUnload': true,
                'authorizeUrl': '@Url.Action("SomeMethod","SomeController")',
                'onProgress': function (file, percent) {
                    $("upload_progress", percent, "%");
                },
                'progressBarId': "upload_progress",
                'onSuccess': function (file, data) {
                    $("#video_id").val(data.id);
                }
            });
     });
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why this works. For example, you do not state that you are using jQuery.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9 and you should input your code in $(document).ready();   Then input ";" after this line $("#panda_video_id").val(data.id) in your code.